# Return an Oracle Associative Array from a function

Tags: oracle, plsql, associative-array, parameter-passing

Does anybody know if it is possible to return an associative array as the result of an Oracle function, if so do you have any examples?

I have an Oracle package which contains an associative array declaration as defined below:

```
TYPE EVENTPARAM IS TABLE OF NUMBER
    INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
```

This is then used in a stored procedure outside the package as follows:

```
v_CompParams areva_interface.eventparam;
```

The intention is to store an associative array of strings in the variable v_CompParams, returned from a Parse function in another package.  The definition for which is as follows:

```
PACKAGE STRING_MANIP  
IS 

    TYPE a_array IS TABLE OF NUMBER 
        INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER; 

    FUNCTION Parse (v_string VARCHAR2, v_delim VARCHAR2) RETURN a_array; 
    FUNCTION RowCount(colln IN a_array) RETURN NUMBER;

END;
```

The code which implements this is:

```
v_CompParams := STRING_MANIP.PARSE(v_CompID,v_Delim);
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work, I get the error 'PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type'.  I foolishly assumed, that since a_array derives from the same source Oracle type as the variable v_CompParams, that there would be no problem casting between them.  Any help much appreciated.

Kind Regards

Paul J.

Comment: You have two types, one in areva_interface, one in string_manip - so they're not the same type (even if they have identical structure).

Answer (score 6):

To be of the very "same" type, v_CompParams must be defined as:

```
v_CompParams STRING_MANIP.a_array;
```